# Passing model class to function changes behavior

Tags: python, django, csv

The first set of python code properly imports an entire CSV file. However, if I try to pass the model ZipMHA as a parameter, it only imports the first line of the CSV file. Can anybody explain this change in behavior when passing the model into the function?

```
import csv
from bah_api.models import withDependents, withOutDependents, ZipMHA

# Populate CSV file into model
def LoadCSV(file_location, delim):
    f = open(file_location)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim)
    for row in csv_f:
        i = 1
        # create a model instance   
        target_model = ZipMHA()
        #loop through the rows
        for y in row:
            setattr(target_model, target_model._meta.fields[i].name, y)
            i += 1
        # save each row
        target_model.save()
    f.close()

LoadCSV("BAH2015/sorted_zipmha15.txt", ' ')
```

Model passed as parameter (only reads first line):

```
# Populate CSV file into model
def LoadCSV(file_location, my_model, delim):
    f = open(file_location)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim)
    for row in csv_f:
        i = 1
        # create a model instance   
        target_model = my_model
        #loop through the rows
        for y in row:
            setattr(target_model, target_model._meta.fields[i].name, y)
            i += 1
        # save each row
        target_model.save()
    f.close()

LoadCSV("BAH2015/sorted_zipmha15.txt", ZipMHA(), ' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the model instance instead of the model class.  Creation of the `target_model` instance should be like this:

```
target_model = my_model() # note the round brackets
```

And call the function without the brackets after the `ZipMHA` class name:

```
LoadCSV("BAH2015/sorted_zipmha15.txt", ZipMHA, ' ')
```